# Implementing generic interface without specifying generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create generic interface and dont specify generic class when I implement this interface

```
public interface IThis<T>
{
    T this[int id] { get; }
}

public class Student : IThis<Student> // i dont want repeat Student in this
{
    public Student this[int id]
    {
        get => new Student();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you even *can* omit it? How should anyone know to which generic argument you concern?

Comment: What you want is called a [shape trait](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ross/publications/shapes/shapes-pldi14.pdf), but no programming language implements them. You always have to repeat the class name in situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t omit the explicit type argument; C# won’t let you.  You *must* specify a type argument for every type variable that appears in a generic supertype.

A type variable (also called a *generic parameter*) is a placeholder for some other type that will be specified when instantiating or implementing a generic type.  The compiler won’t infer the type arguments for you—at least not in a type declaration.